# Make Rows of DATAGRID (NOT DATAGRIDVIEW) Clickable

Tags: c#, winforms

As the title says, I want to make the rows of a DataGrid clickable.
The DataGrid is populated from a MySQL database and I want a situation where when a row is clicked I can perform action just like you would a button on click. Any help?

Comment: You want each cell to be clickable?

Comment: @Harry row. but if all cells on a row can point to the same thing, then that's fine too

Comment: take a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12298/Clickable-Rows-in-a-DataGrid and possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197592/datagrid-clickable-row let me know if these help

Comment: @Harry that's for ASP.NET . . . How do I adapt it for winforms?

Comment: Please update your question to reflect what you are after, I missed the winforms tag.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790181/wpf-datagrid-row-double-click-event-programmatically

Comment: @Harry I just want the row (or cells) to be clickable sort of like a button.